# Typoscript: How to keep parent menuitem status active while a child is selected

Tags: typo3, parent, typoscript

I want the menu item of the parent text to be BOLD while a child is active, how can I arrange this with HMENU of typoscript?

Answer (score 1):

ACT is what you have to look for: http://wiki.typo3.org/TSref/MENUITEM

If that does not suffice you can always use a user function.